# Minimization of open word documents

Tags: file-io, ms-word, document, minimize

I am using this code to get and minimize all open Word documents.

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Documents docs = wordApp.Documents;

wordApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
wordApp.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
```

But documents list is empty despite the fact that I have open Word 2010 documents in Windows 7. Also minimization is not working.

How can I get and minimize all open Word documents?

Answer (score 1):

new Word.Application() will always create a new instance of Word.

to connect to an existing instance, you can use

```
Word.Application wordApp = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
```

(this is similar to the VB/VBA "GetObject" function).

Then you should be able to access your documents.